# SQL teradata - Regex numerical digits

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

can you think of any way to improve this regular expression in SQL teradata?

The idea is to extract all the numerical digits after the word 'tel'.

```
sel regexp_replace(regexp_substr(lower('Hi there - Tel: 2211197245 (cel)'),'tel.*\s*:\s*(.*)'),'[^0-9]+','') as cel;
sel regexp_replace(regexp_substr(lower('Hi there - Telnet: 2211-197245 (mybro)'),'tel.*\s*:\s*(.*)'),'[^0-9]+','') as cel;
sel regexp_replace(regexp_substr(lower('Hi there - Telephone: (2211) 197245 (cel)'),'tel.*\s*:\s*(.*)'),'[^0-9]+','') as cel;

Output: 2211197245
```

Comment: What are the rules to match a phone number? Is there a min/max number of digits? Are there other groups of digits in that string or is the phone number the only one?

Comment: Rather new to regex, but maybe something along [these](https://regex101.com/r/TN1rNz/1) lines. Join group 1 & 2. Assuming you might have digits before `Tel`

Comment: I don't see any examples where you have numbers before the word `tel`. Is that a possibility?

Comment: No, in all cases the phone number appears after the string 'tel'.

Comment: Is there something wrong with your current regex?